# How does A* search select the next node, when nodes with the same heauristic value get added?

Tags: algorithm, search, artificial-intelligence, a-star, motion-planning

**I have a basic understanding of the concept but a model answer given by a lecturer confused me,**

[image]

**I'm confused over the fact how (2,3)B node is expanded ahead of (2,3)A node which in theory gets added to the queue first(Before node B is added)**

This tree is a graphical representation of the shortest path evaluation of a grid. **This tree does not mean that (2,3)A node Do not have children** actually they refer to the same location in the grid, Can someone clarify what I'm missing? Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Can you elaborate on what your cost function and heuristic functions are? What does the f refer to in the diagram above?

Comment: Gotcha. So if you're dumping these nodes into a priority queue based on this evaluation function, then it looks like A and B have the same total cost, right? If that's the case then it's up to the specific implementation to decide which node to expand from. In this case, it just looks like it took B first.

Comment: that's the value of the evaluation function, which is the actual cost + heuristic cost, the heuristic function used is h(x) = (4 − r) + (c − 1), where r and c refer to the x and y coordinates of the node in the grid. where else the cost function is the distance of the node from the start node.

Comment: Interesting, Is that supposed to be a random choice? or the same choice for the entire implementation(i.e Always take the last added node first)

Comment: Usually for a priority queue, if two elements have the same priority then they are served in queue order - so that would be first in first out (FIFO).

Comment: Yeah that's the scenario I'm having problems with, if it's FIFO node A has to be evaluated before node B, Even if we assume it's a LIFO still it contradicts, in that case, Node A has to be evaluated even before (1,3) let alone node B. (since [1,3] and Node A have the same f value)

Comment: Oh I see what you're saying. Node A got added to the queue first since (2,2) had a lower cost than (1,3) - in which case I think I agree with you and that node A should have been expanded first. So this might just be a flaw in the example?

Comment: @doggie_breath Not so!  It is implementation dependent.  Suppose you are using a heap, that takes the element on the left first in the case of ties.  If your two of the same priority went in on the same level of the heap, it comes out in insertion order.  But if the second one started a new heap level, it comes out reversed.

Comment: @btilly Ah! Thank you. Darn those heaps.

Comment: Got it! thanks for the clarification :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is that it is up to the priority queue implementation.

Take the usual [heap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heap_(data_structure)) implementation with an array.  The elements are ordered like this:

```
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
```

But below position `i` the next two are `2i+1` and `2i+2`.  So the array is a tree structure that looks like this:

```
[0,
  [1,
    [3, [7, 8]],
    [4, [9, 10]]]],
  [2, [5, 6]]]
```

Now suppose that `3, 5` have the same priority as each other and so to `6, 7`.  And those 4 were added in that order.  Also suppose that the heap drops the top (left, however you think of it) element first on ties.  Then as you extract, we will eventually get `3` and `5` to the bottom and `3` drops first.  But as you continue extracting, you eventually get a tie between `6, 7` and now `7` is on the top (left, however you orient your thinking) and so it drops first.

The result is that the priority queue guarantees that things come out in priority order, but do NOT have other guarantees on the order.  So things of the same priority can come out in any order.

This is directly related to why [Heapsort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heapsort) is not a stable sort.